# Finding intersections

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, optimization, localization

Given a scenario where there are millions of potentially overlapping bounding boxes of variable sizes less the 5km in width.

Create a fast function with the arguments findIntersections(Longitude,Latitude,Radius) and the output is a list of those bounding boxes ids where each bounding box origin is inside the perimeter of the function argument dimensions.

How do I solve this problem elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normally done using an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) data structure

dbs like mysql or postgresql have GIS modules that use an r-tree under the hood to quickly retrieve locations within a certain proximity to a point on a map.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree:

> R-trees are tree data structures that
>   are similar to B-trees, but are used
>   for spatial access methods, i.e., for
>   indexing multi-dimensional
>   information; for example, the (X, Y)
>   coordinates of geographical data. A
>   common real-world usage for an R-tree
>   might be: "Find all museums within 2
>   kilometres (1.2 mi) of my current
>   location".
>
> The data structure splits space with
>   hierarchically nested, and possibly
>   overlapping, minimum bounding
>   rectangles (MBRs, otherwise known as
>   bounding boxes, i.e. "rectangle", what
>   the "R" in R-tree stands for).

The [Priority R-Tree](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~yike/prtree/) (PR-tree) is a variant that has a maximum running time of:

```
"O((N/B)^(1-1/d)+T/B) I/Os, where N is the number of d-dimensional (hyper-)
rectangles stored in the R-tree, B is the disk block size, and T is the output
size."
```

In practice most real-world queries will have a much quicker average case run time.

fyi, in addition to the other great code posted, there's some cool stuff like [SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/) and [SQLite R-tree module](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html)

Comment: is it possible to tweek it such that only the bounding boxes that have its center overlapping are returned. hmm seems the problem is about points and not rectangles. I suppose the same technique could be used by reducing the rectangle to a point....

Comment: indeed, you can check if the origin is within the radius. (otherwise, if the problem required that the whole rect be in the region, you'd have to check all 4 corners)

Answer (score 1):

[PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) is an open-source GIS extention for postgresql.

They have [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Intersects.html) and [ST_Intersection](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Intersection.html) functions available.

If your interested you can dig around and see how it's implemented there:

http://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/trunk/postgis/

Comment: great, thanks for that. Looks like a pretty comprehensive implementation. I will dig further, thank you for time.

Comment: about the intersects, what I need is that kind of function, that returns a list of objects. But I suppose this could be used as part of the abstraction. *grin*

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a better more general approach GiST

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiST